# MongoDB WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to set up MongoDB. I followed the tutorial on YouTube, but when I type in:

```
$ mongod
    --directoryperdb
    --dbpath C:/mongodb/data/db
    --logpath C:/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
    --logappend
    --rest
```

It didn't respond

```
all output going to: C:/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
```

instead display:

```
WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder with the name `config` in your mongodb directory and a file with the name `mongodb.conf` in the newly created folder >> (so you should have this arrangement of path) >> C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf

add this to the file mongodb.conf

```
dbpath = C:\mongodb\data
port = 27017
logpath = C:\mongodb\logs
rest = true 
httpinterface = true
```

run this line of code in CMD

```
mongod --config C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf --install
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **mongodb.conf** file, add this line

```
rest = true
```

You can read the manual [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#rest).

If you don't have **mongodb.conf** file, create one in your mongodb folder. Here is the sample snippet for the config file. In my case, let's say create at `C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf`.

```
#This is example config file for MongoDB
dbpath = C:\mongodb\data
port = 27017
logpath = C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
```

And then open command prompt, and you can use either one of following

```
mongod -f C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf
```

or

```
mongod --config C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf
```

Comment: i cannot find this mongodb.conf in the file

Comment: Sorry, went to sleep, still not working, so sad, I am giving up, I find the other way to learn node.js, thanks

Comment: Idk what tutorials you are watching at, but you can just download and try by reading installation steps from mongodb website.

Comment: Add an install flag at the end.
mongod.exe --config C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf --install

Answer (score 1):

All that error means is that you added the `--rest` attribute without adding the `--httpinterface` attribute.  It does not matter if you added it inline or in a config file.

In your config file just put:

```
rest = true
httpinterface = true
```

and this warning will not come up on the command line. It is just telling you that since you did not put it, `mongod` is starting the `--httpinterface` for you.  That being said, this should not be done on production because it is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

File **mongodb.conf**

```
#This is example config file for MongoDB
dbpath = C:\mongodb\data
port = 27017
logpath = C:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log
rest = true 
httpinterface = true
```

**CMD**

```
mongod --config C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf --install
```